# Android: runtime permission granted for writing in storage but still denied (onRequestPermissionsResult e.g.)

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to write an image in the device, using the public external storage. Thus I have 1) written in manifest the permissions tags and 2) used `checkSelfPermission` to request permissions if needed. But I still have this exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/03b3d97bd-5186-4506-97dc-9994b7ce0761 (Permission denied)`.

Why? I already read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous but it doesn't answer my question.

## Formalizing the problem

I have granted the storage permissions on my Android device. Thus, my condition `if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {` (see below) is correctly NOT executed, but its `else` is. And this `else` contains a line to save the file in the storage: however it returns this exception...

## Sources

The aim is to call `saveImageAndShareIt` if the user has granted the permission.

### Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Normally the read one should be implicitly recognized thanks to the write permission.

### In the DialogFragment

Below, the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method. `saveImageAndShareIt` is called if the user accepted to grant the permission.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    System.out.println("onrequestPR");

    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            System.out.println("onrequestPR accepted");
            saveImageAndShareIt();
        }
    }
}
```

`onRequestPermissionsResult` is called by `requestPermissions`, presented below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("last_case1");
        saveImageAndShareIt();
        System.out.println("last_case2");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("peperoni");
    saveImageAndShareIt();
    System.out.println("pizza");
}
```

So if the user has already granted the permission, there is no need to call `requestPermissions` and thus, `saveImageAndShareIt` is directly called (in other words: `onRequestPermissionsResult` doesn't need to be executed to call `saveImageAndShareIt`).

## saveImageAndShareIt

The exception is raised by the instanciation of `FileOutputStream`.

```
private void saveImageAndShareIt() {
    OutputStream output;
    try {
        System.out.println("siasi1");
        output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + image_uuid);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) temp.getDrawable();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        output.close();
        System.out.println("siasi2");
        intent_share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + image_uuid));
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent_share, "Share to"));
        System.out.println("siasi3");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## Stack trace

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/03b3d97bd-5186-4506-97dc-9994b7ce0761 (Permission
>   denied) W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287) W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:223)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:110)
>           at com.example...ClipboardDialogFragment.saveImageAndShareIt(ClipboardDialogFragment.java:115)
>           at com.example...ClipboardDialogFragment.access$300(ClipboardDialogFragment.java:42)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example...ClipboardDialogFragment$1$2$1.onTaskCompleted(ClipboardDialogFragment.java:75)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example...DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:34)
>           at com.example...DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:10)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Comment: Perhaps your problem lies in `saveImageAndShareIt()`. I suggest that you edit your question to post the code to that method, along with the complete Java stack trace.

Comment: It's done, thank you!

Comment: Your stack trace suggests that you are calling `saveImageAndShareIt()` from someplace other than where your question indicates. I see that it is coming from `onPostExecute()` of a `DownloadImageTask`, perhaps started by a `ClipboardDialogFragment`. Perhaps you do not have permission, and it is this other unguarded call to `saveImageAndShareIt()` that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access SD cards and other removable media even with File permission granted. If I remember correctly since KitKat unless user enabled access in built-in documents app.

You need to use [DocumentsProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#client) or obtain yet another permission/uri through [StorageVolume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.html#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String)) and parse it with [DocumentsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract) ([sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScopedDirectoryAccess)).

Edit: based on your exception:

```
 /storage/emulated/03b3d97bd-5186-4506-97dc-9994b7ce0761
```

Default external directory is `/storage/emulated/0`, looks like You forgot to add a separator after directory name:

```
output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+ image_uuid);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I just have a byte array of an image, and want to save it in the gallery of the user...

Comment: The code in the question is writing to external storage, not removable storage.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler by default SD cards are mounted as read-only (on system level) and You need to jump through all those hoops to have elevated system apps write to it for You. Of course You might find some devices/users that can obtain write permission to it, but at this point those are exceptions more than a rule.

Comment: @CommonsWare direct `File` access is such an API disaster at this point, but Your comment made me realize something (I edit my answer).

Comment: adding the forward `/` should fix it, because it starts with `0`. for an image a suffix wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Was mislead by that filename, thought its mounted SD card UUID for some reason

Comment: @Pawel that UUID string might be misinterpreted as index of the emulated storage, which does not exist.

Comment: Good catch on the missing `/`. This is why I always recommend that developers not use concatenation to create filesystem paths. Changing `new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + image_uuid)` to `new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), image_uuid)` would have avoided that problem. Plus, it is 1 character shorter. :-)